Ansible mount module won't do state ephemeral
According to Ansible's documentation for the ansible.posix.mount module there is a state called ephemeral which mounts your share but does not modify the fstab file, if I am understanding this correctly.
Ansible mount module documentation
This method is ideal because I don't want my password exposed in clear text.
Here is my code:
- name: Mounting NAS2 share
      mount:
        path: /mnt/images
        src: //10.2.103.32/images
        fstype: cifs
        opts: "username=image,password={{ nas2_images }}"
        state: ephemeral

The error I get when I run the task is:
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "value of state must be one of: absent, mounted, present, unmounted, remounted, got: ephemeral"}

I thought maybe my ansible.posix was old and so I upgraded it to 1.5.4 and I still get the same error.
If someone could get me pointed in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.
Created the share /mnt/images and set permissions to 755, owner and group to ansible.
Created ansible task and got the error in my post.
Upgraded ansible.posix

To remount a mount point not registered in 'fstab', use `ephemeral' instead, especially with BSD nodes.
In my view it says that 'ephemeral' cannot be used to mount a share but remount (refresh) it.

@macosmi can you explain what they mean by this in the documentation for ephemeral? If the mount point is not present, the mount point will be created.

Yeah, it looks to me like it can be used when regular mounting to me. Something like this would be super important when dealing with Windows nodes and file transfer and using CIFS. For security best practices, a temporary mount that does not get recorded in fstab is ideal so that your password does not get stored in clear text in fstab.
You can mount it and then dismount it of course, but if your script crashes in the middle, your credentials are left in fstab.
Please correct me if I am wrong because I am not an expert Linux user.

@JasonGarner
Let me say that 'ansible.posix.mount' module is not the same as generic 'mount' module in Ansible (which you used in your playbook). I can't see 'ephemeral' option in 'mount' module. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/mount_module.html
Maybe that's why you received this kind of error.
I wonder what happens if you change module from 'mount' to 'ansible.posix.mount' in your playbook.

@Squashman you are right - I was too quick and possibly wrong to state that 'ephemeral' state in ansible.posix.module cannot be used to mount a share.

@macosmi That must be it! Thank you! I will try this out.

Nope. I changed the namespace to ansible.posix.mount and I get the same error.
TASK [Mount the Windows share to /tmp/windows] ********************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "value of state must be one of: absent, mounted, present, unmounted, remounted, got: ephemeral"}

@JasonGarner Tried to simulate your issue on my ground. Applied 'state: ephemeral' to share  nfs between two linux machines and  it worked. Additionally, as you mentioned, this didn't add the share to /etc/fstab like 'state: mounted' option did.
- name: mount nfs share
  mount:
    fstype: nfs
    path: /home/maco/nfs
    src: 192.168.122.1:/var/log
    state: ephemeral
- name:
  shell: "ls /home/maco/nfs"

current version ansible/python:
python version = 3.9.18
ansible [core 2.14.14]
Maybe it gives you some clue and helps.

You will have to add more debugging information, specifically some more proof of the version of ansible.posix you are effectively using other than just I upgraded it to 1.5.4, because your error message clearly shows you are using a version below 1.5.0 (as this is the version where that state was added). My 2 cent: remove any installed collections in ~/.ansible/collections (or back them up somewhere else), create a fresh python venv, activate it, pip install ansible and then try again

Thank you, gentlemen! With your suggestions I figured it out.
My first confusion was of course not knowing there was a mount and also an ansible.posix.mount.
My second confusion was updating the ansible.posix module to 1.5.4 which said "Inst alled Successfully" in my terminal so I didn't think anything else of it. However, when I went back and listed my galaxy modules, ansible.posix was still at 1.1.1. I then updated ansible core to which was 2.13 to 2.16 and I went back and listed the modules and ansible.posix was at 1.5.4.
Ran my playbook and the share was mounted with no fstab.

Thank you. With your suggestions I figured it out.
My first confusion was of course not knowing there was a mount and also an ansible.posix.mount.
My second confusion was updating the ansible.posix module to 1.5.4 which said "Inst alled Successfully" in my terminal so I didn't think anything else of it. However, when I went back and listed my galaxy modules, ansible.posix was still at 1.1.1. I then updated ansible core to which was 2.13 to 2.16 and I went back and listed the modules and ansible.posix was at 1.5.4.
Ran my playbook and the share was mounted with no fstab.
